# How to get the id from dynamically created button by clicking the same button which is created by Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have created a html button using jquery(ajax) which is holding the id this id is generated from the ajax call data. That code is created number of buttons i want generate click event for that each button and i want to get the id for each button i have tried like this but am unable to retrieve the id.

**The button id is like this**

```
id=" + "btnMv" + "" + data.d[i].id + "" + "
```

**My code is like this :** 
**Jquery**

```
<button type="+ "submit" + "  value="+ data.d[i].id + "  id=" + "btnMv" + "" + data.d[i].id + "" + ">  Name : " + data.d[i].Name + "</button>   

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnMv').click(function () {
    var a = (this).attr("value");
    alert(a);
});
});
```

Help me how to solve this.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do. if you creating many buttons they should have different `id`s.

Comment: Yes that is creating many buttons so am trying get each and every id by clicking on every button

Comment: It's better to use `class`, not `id` in your case

Comment: Maybe you are right when ever am using id is static and value is dynamic i  am able to get the value but when ever am trying to give dynamic id's am unable to get the id thanx for comment .... @teo van kot

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
      var a = (this).attr("value");
      alert(a);
   });
});
```